# Finding Key associated with max Value in a Java Map

Tags: java, hashmap

What is the easiest way to get key associated with the max value in a map?

I believe that Collections.max(someMap) will return the max Key, when you want the key that corresponds to the max value.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Basically you'd need to iterate over the map's entry set, remembering both the "currently known maximum" and the key associated with it. (Or just the entry containing both, of course.)

For example:

```
Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> maxEntry = null;

for (Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0)
    {
        maxEntry = entry;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: You can have more than one key with the same maximum value.  This loop will give you the first one it finds.

Comment: Changing > 0 to >= 0 will give you the last one it finds

Comment: Would Java 8 streams usage help in simplifying this anymore?
e.x: map.forEach((k,v) -> ...

Comment: @zkarthik: Using `max` with a custom comparator would probably be simpler.

Comment: I had to pass in a `Comparator<V> cmp` parameter and compare values using `cmp.compare(entry.getValue(), maxEntry.getValue()) > 0)`

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal: If you want to add additional options, please add a new answer rather than editing an existing one.

Answer (score 178):

For completeness, here is a [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) way of doing it

**Cleanest way:**

```
Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey()
```

or

```
countMap.entrySet().stream().max((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1).get().getKey();
```

or

```
Collections.max(countMap.entrySet(), (entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() - entry2.getValue()).getKey();
```

or

```
Collections.max(countMap.entrySet(), Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)).getKey();
```

Comment: `(entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() - entry2.getValue()` is more compact for the comparator.

Comment: What to do if i want all keys that match the max value?

Comment: Compact but hard to understand.

Comment: You can also use the compare method provided by the Integer class
`countMap.entrySet().stream().max((entry1, entry2) -> Integer.compare(entry1.getValue(), entry2.getValue())).get().getKey();`

Comment: Or you can use `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` instead

Comment: Thanks Alexey - Now the third solution from Hilikus would become more consise like this `Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();`.

Answer (score 81):

A simple one liner using Java-8

```
Key key = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
```

Comment: @Samir https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey()

Comment: @Samir, Please check you Java version.  Sleiman Jneid has explicitly mentioned  that it will work with Java 8

Comment: @Vaibs I was using Java 8. It doesn't matter anymore, Hilikus' answer worked for me.

Comment: It works for me like this:

`String max_key = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();`

Comment: what if there are 2 such key that are max? how can it return an array of such key values?

Comment: @Sophie maps don't allow duplicate keys.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi The question doesn't ask about the duplicate keys.
Consider a situation like this :-
<1,8>
<2,8>
<5,4>
<4,6>
<6,7>
There are 2 keys with maximum value 8. So it should return 1,2.

Comment: Nice, short and easy to understand

Answer (score 71):

This code will print all the keys with maximum value

```
public class NewClass4 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<Integer,Integer>map=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        map.put(1, 50);
        map.put(2, 60);
        map.put(3, 30);
        map.put(4, 60);
        map.put(5, 60);
        int maxValueInMap=(Collections.max(map.values()));  // This will return max value in the HashMap
        for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {  // Iterate through HashMap
            if (entry.getValue()==maxValueInMap) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());     // Print the key with max value
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it should be "Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: valmap.entrySet()"

Answer (score 11):

Here's how do do it directly (without an explicit extra loop) by defining the appropriate `Comparator`:

```
int keyOfMaxValue = Collections.max(
                        yourMap.entrySet(), 
                        new Comparator<Entry<Double,Integer>>(){
                            @Override
                            public int compare(Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
                                return o1.getValue() > o2.getValue()? 1:-1;
                            }
                        }).getKey();
```

Answer (score 10):

**1. Using Stream**

```
public <K, V extends Comparable<V>> V maxUsingStreamAndLambda(Map<K, V> map) {
    Optional<Entry<K, V>> maxEntry = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max((Entry<K, V> e1, Entry<K, V> e2) -> e1.getValue()
            .compareTo(e2.getValue())
        );
     
    return maxEntry.get().getKey();
}
```

**2. Using Collections.max()  with a Lambda Expression**

```
    public <K, V extends Comparable<V>> V maxUsingCollectionsMaxAndLambda(Map<K, V> map) {
        Entry<K, V> maxEntry = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), (Entry<K, V> e1, Entry<K, V> e2) -> e1.getValue()
            .compareTo(e2.getValue()));
        return maxEntry.getKey();
    }
```

**3. Using Stream with Method Reference**

```
    public <K, V extends Comparable<V>> V maxUsingStreamAndMethodReference(Map<K, V> map) {
        Optional<Entry<K, V>> maxEntry = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
        return maxEntry.get()
            .getKey();
    }
```

**4. Using Collections.max()**

```
    public <K, V extends Comparable<V>> V maxUsingCollectionsMax(Map<K, V> map) {
        Entry<K, V> maxEntry = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), new Comparator<Entry<K, V>>() {
            public int compare(Entry<K, V> e1, Entry<K, V> e2) {
                return e1.getValue()
                    .compareTo(e2.getValue());
            }
        });
        return maxEntry.getKey();
    }
```

**5. Using Simple Iteration**

```
public <K, V extends Comparable<V>> V maxUsingIteration(Map<K, V> map) {
    Map.Entry<K, V> maxEntry = null;
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue()
            .compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0) {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }
    return maxEntry.getKey();
}
```

Comment: `3. Using Stream with Method Reference` is quite cool.

Answer (score 7):

An answer that returns an Optional since the map may have no max value if it is empty:
`map.entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).map(Map.Entry::getKey);`

Answer (score 7):

I have two methods, using this méthod to get the key with the max value:

```
 public static Entry<String, Integer> getMaxEntry(Map<String, Integer> map){        
    Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = null;
    Integer max = Collections.max(map.values());

    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Integer value = entry.getValue();
        if(null != value && max == value) {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }
    return maxEntry;
}
```

As an example gettin the Entry with the max value using the method:

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry =  getMaxEntry(map);
```

---

Using **Java 8** we can get an object containing the max value:

```
Object maxEntry = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();      

System.out.println("maxEntry = " + maxEntry);
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple to understand.
In Below code, maxKey is the key which is holding the max value.

```
int maxKey = 0;
int maxValue = 0;
for(int i : birds.keySet())
{
    if(birds.get(i) > maxValue)
    {
        maxKey = i;
        maxValue = birds.get(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 way to get all keys with max value.

```
Integer max = PROVIDED_MAP.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1)
            .get()
            .getValue();

List listOfMax = PROVIDED_MAP.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == max)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(listOfMax);
```

Also you can parallelize it by using `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()`

Answer (score 4):

**given map**

HashMap abc = new HashMap<>();

**get all map entries with a maximum of values.**

you can use any of the below methods in the filter to get respective map entries for sets of minimum or maximum values

```
Collections.max(abc.values())
Collections.min(abc.values())
Collections.max(abc.keys())
Collections.max(abc.keys())

abc.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == Collections.max(abc.values()))
```

**if only want to get the keys for the filter map**

```
abc.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == Collections.max(abc.values()))
       .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

**if you want to get the values for the filtered map**

```
abc.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == Collections.max(abc.values()))
      .map(Map.Entry::getvalue)
```

**if you want to get all such keys in a list:**

```
abc.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == Collections.max(abc.values()))
  .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

**if you want to get all such values in a list:**

```
abc.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == Collections.max(abc.values()))
  .map(Map.Entry::getvalue)
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this solution ok?

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 };
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i : a) {
Integer count = map.get(i);
map.put(i, count != null ? count + 1 : 0);
}
Integer max = Collections.max(map.keySet());
System.out.println(max);
System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int maxValue = 0;
int mKey = 0;
for(Integer key: map.keySet()){
    if(map.get(key) > maxValue){
        maxValue = map.get(key);
        mKey = key;
    }
}
System.out.println("Max Value " + maxValue + " is associated with " + mKey + " key");
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this forum. Please edit your answer to include an explanation of your code. How does it solve OP's problem?

Answer (score 1):

Majority Element/ max element in the map :

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] a = {1,3,4,3,4,3,2,3,3,3,3,3};
     List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
     Map<Integer, Long> map = list.parallelStream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));
     System.out.println("Map => " + map);
     //{1=1, 2=1, 3=8, 4=2}
     map.entrySet()
     .stream()
     .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))//compare the values and get the maximum value
     .map(Entry::getKey)// get the key appearing maximum number of times
     .ifPresentOrElse(System.out::println,() -> new RuntimeException("no such thing"));

     /*
      * OUTPUT : Map => {1=1, 2=1, 3=8, 4=2} 
      * 3
      */
     // or in  this way 
     System.out.println(".............");
     Integer maxAppearedElement = map.entrySet()
             .parallelStream()
             .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
             .map(Entry::getKey)
             .get();
     System.out.println(maxAppearedElement);

     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my project, I used a slightly modified version of Jon's and Fathah's solution. In the case of multiple entries with the same value, it returns the last entry it finds:

```
public static Entry<String, Integer> getMaxEntry(Map<String, Integer> map) {        
    Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = null;
    Integer max = Collections.max(map.values());

    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Integer value = entry.getValue();

        if(null != value && max == value) {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }

    return maxEntry;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to return the keys with max value in a `Map<Integer, Integer>`

```
public Set<Integer> getMaxKeys(Map<Integer, Integer> map) { 

        if (map.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        return map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(
            groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getValue, TreeMap::new, mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toSet())
            )
         )
         .lastEntry()
         .getValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**:

```kotlin
val key = map.toList().groupingBy { it }.eachCount().maxByOrNull { it.value }?.key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int max = 0;
// here m is a HashMap<String, Integer>
    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : m.entrySet()){

       if(entry.getValue() > max){
          max = entry.getValue();              
       }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't show how the key for the corresponding max value is retrieved.

Answer (score -1):

you can do like that

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
hm.put(1,10);
hm.put(2,45);
hm.put(3,100);
Iterator<Integer> it = hm.keySet().iterator();
Integer fk = it.next();
Integer max = hm.get(fk);
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Integer k = it.next();
    Integer val = hm.get(k);
    if (val > max){
         max = val;
         fk=k;
    }
}
System.out.println("Max Value "+max+" is associated with "+fk+" key");
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way is:

```
Collections.max(hmap.values());
```

Comment: This would return the largest _value_, rather than the largest _key_ associated to it