# Retrieve N most relevant objects in Java TreeMap

Tags: java, performance, dictionary

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java) I have ordered a Java `Map`, as follows:

```
ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(originalMap);
Map<String,Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String,Integer>(bvc);
sortedMap.putAll(originalMap);
```

Now, I would like to extract the `K` most relevant values from the map, in top-K fashion. Is there a highly efficient way of doing it without iterating through the map?

P.S., some similar questions (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911174/finding-key-associated-with-max-value-in-a-java-map)) ask for a solution to the top-1 retrieval problem.

Comment: I would strongly discourage you from using that implementation. Did you read the comments on the top answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java#comment4699669_1283722

Comment: Ups, did not notice it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not if you use a `Map`. You'd have to iterate over it.

Have you considered using a `PriorityQueue`? It's Java's implementation of a heap. It has efficient operations for insertion of arbitrary elements and for removal of the "minimum". You might think about doing this here. Instead of a `Map`, you could put them into a `PriorityQueue` ordered by relevance, with the most relevant as the root. Then, to extract the *K* most relevant, you'd just pop *K* elements from the `PriorityQueue`.

If you need the map-like property (mapping from `String` to `Integer`), then you could write a class that internally keeps everything in both a `PriorityQueue` and a `HashMap`. When you insert, you insert into both; when you remove the minimal element, you pop from the `PriorityQueue`, and that then tells you which element you also need to remove from your `HashMap`. This will still give you log-time inserts and min-removals.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to keep two values (a String and an Integer) in the map. I need them both. I thought about putting in a Queue an Entry<String,Integer>, but in this case the operation queue.contains(<any tuple with a specified String key>) is difficult to be implemented

Comment: @Eleanore I've added something to the question about this.