# Print out the key and maximum value in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Hi I have the following HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> normalised = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

and would like to print out the highest value in the map and its associated key.

Could anyone help I tried using the following code to no avail

```
        String maxKey=null;
        int maxValue = Interger.MIN_VALUE; 
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : normalised.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue() > maxValue) {
             maxValue = entry.getValue();
             maxKey = entry.getKey();
        }
    }
```

Can someone guide to as where I am going wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks good, what result do you have? how do you initialise the map?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me except for the typo "Interger".

Comment: @Shashank ermahgerd, interger!

Answer (score 1):

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer> maxEntry = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry :normalised.entrySet()){
    if (maxEntry == null ||entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0){
        maxEntry = entry;
    }
}
```

If there are multiple keys with same maximum values though, you will get the first key with the max value.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works if you correct the typo "Interger" to "Integer".
See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5911199/4602991

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine :

```
HashMap<String, Integer> normalised = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
String maxKey=null;
long maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
for(String key : normalised.keySet()) {
    if(normalised.get(key).longValue() > maxValue) {
        maxValue = entry.getValue().longValue();
        maxKey = entry.getKey();
    }
}
```