# How to check for an amount of a certain data type in list?

Tags: java

I am writing an UnoPlayer.java code for a main method that has already been written out in order to test the legality of our UnoPlayer method.

I am trying to check to see if the amount of one color (a data type) in my hand is greater than the amount of the other colors.

hand is a list type!!

So, for Color.BLUE, I have this:

```
if (hand.contains(Color.BLUE > Color.RED && Color.GREEN && Color.YELLOW)) {
    colorReturned = Color.BLUE;
}
```

I know that this does not work because my Color data type does not work with binary operands because they are not ints. How would I code it so that it says

//if (hand contains more Color.BLUE than the rest of the colors) {

//returns Color.BLUE }

here is the card implementation:

```
private UnoPlayer.Color color;
private UnoPlayer.Rank rank;
private int number;

public Card(UnoPlayer.Color color, UnoPlayer.Rank rank) {
    this.color = color;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.number = -1;
}


public Card(UnoPlayer.Color color, int number) {
    this.color = color;
    this.rank = UnoPlayer.Rank.NUMBER;
    this.number = number;
}


public Card(UnoPlayer.Color color, UnoPlayer.Rank rank, int number) {
    this.color = color;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.number = number;
}
```

Comment: What type of variable is `hand`?

Comment: @ChrisGong hand is a list! sorry for not specifying

Comment: A list of `int` or `Integer`?

Comment: @ChrisGong it is a list of the data type Card...i'm not really sure how to tell what it is. all i know is that a Card type has a Color(R,G,B,Y) a Rank(Number,Reverse,Skip,Wild, Wild_d4) and a number 0-9 if it is of the number rank

Comment: Could you post your implementation for `Card`, I posted an answer that assumes `hand` is a list of ints/integers, so the logic is the same but you have to adjust for your data type.

Comment: @ChrisGong edited my question so it shows the card implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using `contains` correctly, according to [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-), the method `contains` returns a boolean variable (`true` or `false` depending on whether a value exists in the list). However you're inputting a boolean expression, when `contains` takes an `Object` as a parameter.

My suggestion to checking if a certain data type occurs the most in a list, I would first sort the list, then keep count of the highest occurring data type like so,

```
Collections.sort(hand);
int prev = hand.get(0);
int occursMost = hand.get(0);
int count = 1;
int maxCount = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < hand.length; i++) {
    if (a.get(i) == prev)
        count++;
    else {
        if (count > maxCount) {
            popular = a.get(i-1);
            maxCount = count;
        }
        prev = hand.get(i);
        count = 1;
    }
}
if(occursMost == Color.BLUE) {
    colorReturned = Color.BLUE;
}
```

A little bit how this works, so let's say your hand looks like this

```
GREEN, BLUE, RED, GREEN, BLUE, BLUE
```

I'm not quite sure about the int values behind the colors but after sorting, the hand could looks like this,

```
GREEN, GREEN, RED, BLUE, BLUE, BLUE
```

The loop will start at green, then keep incrementing `count` until a different color is found. Once a different color is found, `count` is checked with `maxCount` to see if the most popular color so far has been found. Then it resets `count` and starts counting the occurrences of the next color in the list. At the end of the loop, the most popular color in the list should be set.

Comment: i sort of understand that, but i'm only in a 200 course so we have never used maxCount, Collections, or popular. also, hand is full of the data type Card so it says it cannot be converted to an int with those initializations at the top of your code. i will post implementation for the card data type

Comment: @hattic my apologies for being inactive, I just got back. I just wanted to confirm that you were able to solve your issue or do you still need help because I can assist in modifying the code above to fit your `Card` class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming hand is a list of Cards, where each Card has a color (as in the game of Uno), you probably want to write a loop, keeping track of the number of times each color has come. You then return the one with max count.

```
List<Card> hand;
Map<Color, Integer> colorCount = new HashMap<>();
for (Card card : hand) {
   int currentCount = colorCount.get(card.getColor()) == null ? 0 : colorCount.get(card.getColor());
   colorCount.put(card.getColor(), currentCount + 1);
}
```

In Java 8:

```
List<Card> hand;
Map<Color, Integer> colorCount = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(card -> colorCount.put(card.getColor(), 1 + colorCount.getOrDefault(card.getColor(), 0)));
```

And see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5911199/1675971) to get the color with max count from the map.

Comment: That's what I attempted to do with the code I have up there, but i got the error bad operand types for for binary operator '>'. i dont know the correct syntax to check for a certain int value of how many blues are in my deck.

the hand class is already a part of the given .java, i am only making my own player method

Comment: See the code added for getting the count. Also see Chris's answer on why using `contains` is wrong.