# How I can find a key ordered in ascending order in treemap, if there are more than one max values?

Tags: java, treemap

I have a `TreeMap` with entries like

```
["aftab" = 4, "Manoj" = 5, "Rahul" = 5]
```

I want to get the key with the max value, but if there are two or more max values I want the key that comes first in the map, `Manoj` in this case. In My application I used `Collections.max(map.getKey())` and it is returning `Rahul`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding Key associated with max Value in a Java Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911174/finding-key-associated-with-max-value-in-a-java-map)

Comment: Yes, It was a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Comparator` and pass it to `Collections.max()`.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(
            Map.of("Aftab", 4, "Manoj", 5, "Rahul", 5));

Comparator<Entry<String,Integer>> comp = Entry.comparingByValue();

Entry<String,Integer> e = Collections.max(map.entrySet(),comp);

System.out.println(e);
// or
System.out.println(e.getKey());
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a comparator that sorts the entries by values descending then comparing by keys when two values are equals

```
Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
.thenComparing(Entry.comparingByKey())
```

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("aftab", 4);
map.put("Manoj", 5);
map.put("Rahul", 5);
Entry<String, Integer> result = map.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed().thenComparing(Entry.comparingByKey()))
                .findFirst().orElseGet(null);

System.out.println(result);
```

, output

```
Manoj=5
```

Comment: this answer is also correct, but for me little complex. And It should print only  "manoj".

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collections::max` to find the entry with maximum value from `map.entrySet()` by using `Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)`.

## Demo:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
        map.put("aftab", 4);
        map.put("Manoj", 5);
        map.put("Rahul", 5);

        Entry<String, Integer> entry = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue));
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Manoj=5
```

Comment: Yes @Arvind Kumar Avinash, Your answer is absolutely correct.