# How to return key associated to highest value in nested map (Java)?

Tags: java

I am trying to build a simple program that in essence will return the key associated to the highest value in a nested Map. For example (below numbers are just an example, they are not real).

```
public class MultiValueMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> singers = new HashMap<>();
        singers.put("Elvis", new HashMap<>());
        singers.get("Elvis").put("All Shook up", 8);
        singers.get("Elvis").put("Don't be Cruel", 5);
        singers.get("Elvis").put("Viva las Vegas", 3);

    }

}
```

The idea here is to get either the top song or lowest rated song. The program should return for example "All Shook Up" if I want the top rated song.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: Learning means trial and error. Even posting a false attempt or just proposing an approach (like in pseudo-code) can be a big step towards the solution. Thus [ask] requires a [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Given

Given your map with

```
singer_map: interpret -> title_map
title_map: title -> rating
```

like:

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> singers = new HashMap<>();
singers.put("Elvis", new HashMap<>());
singers.get("Elvis").put("All Shook up", 8);
singers.get("Elvis").put("Don't be Cruel", 5);
singers.get("Elvis").put("Viva las Vegas", 3);
```

#### Algorithm

Now define a temporary entry variable for the `favoriteTitle`.
Take the title-map like `Map<String, Integer> titles = singers.get("Elvis")` and iterate over each entry (e.g. a for-each loop).

In the loop-body of each iteration:
If an entry is higher then `favoriteTitle` or `favoriteTitle` is empty, then store the current entry.

After the loop you have the `favoriteTitle` with highest rating for this singer. If the singer has no titles, then there is also no favorite.

What if all or the more than 1 highest rated titles have the same rating?

#### Sample code

```
Map<String, Integer> titles = singers.get("Elvis");
Map.Entry<String, Integer> favoriteTitle;

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> t : titles) {
  System.out.println(t.getKey() + " rated " + t.getValue());
  if (favoriteTitle == null || favoriteTitle.getValue() < t.getValue()) {
    favoriteTitle = t;
  }
}
System.out.println("Favorite: " + favoriteTitle.getKey() + " rated " + favoriteTitle.getValue());
```

See also:

- GeeksforGeeks: [Map.Entry interface in Java with example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-entry-interface-java-example/), tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Note that, given you want `min` and `max` a `HashMap` is not the most suitable structure.
You'll need to traverse over all values every time you want an answer to this question. If you use a `TreeSet` you can reduce that to a simple binary search on all keys.

```
record SongScore(String songName, int score)  {}

....

Map<String, TreeSet<SongScore>> singers = new HashMap<>();
TreeSet<SongScore> songs = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(SongScore::score));
songs.add(new SongScore("All Shook up", 8));
songs.add(new SongScore("Don't be Cruel", 5));
songs.add(new SongScore("Viva las Vegas", 3));
singers.put("Elvis", songs);

var lowest = singers.values().stream().map(TreeSet::first).min(Comparator.comparingInt(SongScore::score));
var highest = singers.values().stream().map(TreeSet::last).max(Comparator.comparingInt(SongScore::score));
```

Comment: Wow, traversing a light-year for a newbie. Concepts like [binary-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), [`TreeSet`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-tree-set), Java8 _streaming_ with `Comparator` and Java14's [`record`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-record-keyword) are rather advanced-level.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8+ use a stream with `Comparator` like in [Finding Key associated with max Value in a Java Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911174/finding-key-associated-with-max-value-in-a-java-map).

Comment: Unless you explain how the linked question/answer applies here, this link-only-answer is better suited as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java8 streams you can use a pretty simple one liner. This example assumes there is at least one entry in the map with a non-null value.

```java
map.entrySet()  // get all entries
   .stream()   // stream over them
   .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))  // max over all entries by value (here: rating), comparing them as integers 
   .get().getKey()  // get the entry, then the key (here: title)
```